# Were these two characters able to reconcile?

Tags: burn-notice

In *Burn Notice*, Fiona reveals that in the past,

> her sister Claire was killed after an argument they had.

Were they at least able to reconcile before the latter died?

Comment: It would be easier for people to research an answer to this question if you could provide some more information. The relevant episode numbers would be a good start.